# Can I autowire (and autodiscover) daos while specifying the entities through a hibernate config?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, annotations, autowired

Basically, I have objects that need to become entities, but the code is generated and I can't touch it (thus I can't use annotations).  I'd like to list them in an xml config.  However, I'd also like spring to autodiscover and autowire the respective daos.  How would I go about setting up my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the component scan how you like (btw: you can have several component scans)

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="regex" expression=".*Dao"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

This example will create beans for all classes thet match the regex and are located within the base package.

@See S[pring Reference Chapter 3.10.3 Using filters to customize scanning](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-filters)

Comment: Ah-ha!  That's what I needed.  Apparently I wasn't "looking" in the right place (some of my daos were in a different package).